# Any way to get Eclipse-like autocompletion in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, ide, intellij-14

Due to internal company changes, I am forced to switch from Eclipse to IntelliJ. Unfortunately, I am extremely dissatisfied with the autocomplete capability of InteliJ.

For example, if I type "swit" and press Enter, Eclipse will generate the following code:

```
switch (key) {
    case value:

        break type;

    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value: " + key);
    }
```

But if I do the same in IntelliJ, I will get this as a result:

```
switch()
```

How can I improve the autocomplete abilities of IntelliJ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Go to Preferences > Editor > Live Templates, you can see which shortcuts are available, and optionally add your own.